# Sort Array of objects with keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying all that I know in javascript. Is there a way to sort this based on key?

```
var myObj =[{"2":"installation.diagnostics.status"},{"4":"installation.diagnostics.status"},{"3":"installation.diagnostics.status"}];
```

Here is my code!!

```
var result=JSON.stringify(navMenu);

eval('var obj='+result);

console.log(obj);
Object.keys(obj)
      .sort()
      .forEach(function (k) {
         console.log(obj[k]);
      });
```

to

```
var myObj =[{"2":"installation.diagnostics.status"},{"3":"installation.diagnostics.status"},{"4":"installation.diagnostics.status"}]
```

Comment: I have tried, and why negative marking!!

var result=JSON.stringify(navMenu);

eval('var obj='+result);

console.log(obj);
Object.keys(obj)
      .sort()
      .forEach(function (k) {
         console.log(obj[k]);
      });

Comment: Then edit you answer to add what you tried, and tell us what you get and what you expected. We aren't here to write your code.

Comment: Fine, I have edited my code, I am not able to get in to the keys and sort it. Its sorting on array keys like 0,1 and 2 not on 2,4,3

Comment: [*Array.prototype.sort*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) accepts a sort function as a parameter. Have a [play with that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: Do the objects always have only one property that's numeric? Otherwise, the question is unclear as to how exactly the sort should take place.

Comment: Yes, one numeric and string. The number can be between 1 to 100. 
just like this.
[{"2":"installation.diagnostics.status"},{"4":"installation.diagnostics.status"},{"3":"installation.diagnostics.status"}]

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
var myObj =[{"2":"installation.diagnostics.status"},{"4":"installation.diagnostics.status"},{"3":"installation.diagnostics.status"}];
```

you can sort that using:

```
myObj.sort(function(a, b){return Object.keys(a)[0] - Object.keys(b)[0]});
```

You may need a polyfill for [*Object.keys*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to support older browsers.

Note that this sorts on the first returned property name as a number. If any member of *myObj* has more than one own property or the first returned isn't a digit, it may not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [comparator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). This is the one to sort by strings which is what the object keys are.

```
function compare(a, b) {
  var ak = Object.keys(a)[0];
  var bk = Object.keys(b)[0];
  if (ak < bk) return -1;
  if (ak > bk) return 1;
  return 0;
}

myObj.sort(compare);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FrJpG/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 (function (s) {
    var t = {};
    Object.keys(s).sort().forEach(function (k) {
        t[k] = s[k]
    });
    return t
})(myObj)
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortArrayOfObjectsByKey(array, key, order){
    // can sort forward or in reverse - can be passed as integer or string
    // if order not passed in, defaults to 1 (forward)
    order = !order ? 1 : order;

    if (order === -1 || order.toString().toLowerCase() === "reverse"){
        array.sort(function(first, second) {
            if (first[key] < second[key]) { return 1; }
            else if (first[key] > second[key]) { return -1; }
            return 0;
        });
    }
    else {
        array.sort(function(first, second) {
            if (first[key] < second[key]) { return -1; }
            else if (first[key] > second[key]) { return 1; }
            return 0;
        });
    }
    return array;
}
```